# Best way to optimize a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get *signature_file*, *signature_date* and *status_id*.
Each one came from subquery and actually, this is my code.

There is the best way to optimize this query, **maybe with one subquery only?**

EXAMPLE (expected)

```
SELECT 
    ID, fck, f1, 
    (SELECT f2, f3 FROM tbl2 Y WHERE Y.ID = T.fck) AS f2, f3
FROM 
    tbl1 T
```

The table where I look is always the same...

```
   SELECT d.*, cd.*,
 
   ( SELECT s.cnt_man_doc_signature_file
     FROM cnt_man_doc_signatures s
     WHERE s.cnt_man_doc_signature_document_id = d.cnt_man_doc_id
     ORDER BY s.cnt_man_doc_signature_id DESC
     LIMIT 1
   )
     AS signature_file,

   ( SELECT s.cnt_man_doc_signature_date
     FROM cnt_man_doc_signatures s
     WHERE s.cnt_man_doc_signature_document_id = d.cnt_man_doc_id
     ORDER BY s.cnt_man_doc_signature_id DESC
     LIMIT 1
   )
     AS signature_date,

   ( SELECT s.cnt_man_doc_signature_status_id
     FROM cnt_man_doc_signatures s
     WHERE s.cnt_man_doc_signature_document_id = d.cnt_man_doc_id
     ORDER BY s.cnt_man_doc_signature_id DESC
     LIMIT 1
   )
     AS status_id

   FROM      cnt_man_docs d
   LEFT JOIN cnt_man_class_doc cd ON cd.cnt_man_class_doc_id = d.cnt_man_doc_class_id
   WHERE     cnt_man_doc_folder_id = ?
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query should be doing.

Comment: Why you are using 4 same subqueries with same condition, only with different column selecting?

Comment: I have addedd on a sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd38ff/2

Comment: I need to get signature_file, signature_date and status_id from cnt_man_doc_signatures table as variables

Answer (score 0):

As Marko pointed out: You're using 4 similar subqueries with different column selecting. You could instead just use that subquery once and pick the desired columns:

```
    SELECT d.*, 
    cd.*, 
    s.cnt_man_doc_signature_file, 
    s.snt_man_doc_signature_doc, 
    s.cnt_man_doc_signature_status_id

       FROM      cnt_man_docs d
       LEFT JOIN cnt_man_class_doc cd ON cd.cnt_man_class_doc_id = d.cnt_man_doc_class_id
       LEFT JOIN cnt_man_doc_signatures s ON s.cnt_man_doc_signature_document_id = d.cnt_man_doc_id
       WHERE     cnt_man_doc_folder_id = ?
```